# On Homeomorphim

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. I want to show that if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous then $\phi:X\to G(f)$ defined by $\phi(x)=(x,f(x))$ is open and continuous, where $G(f)$ is the graph of the function $f$.

To show that $\phi$ is open let $G$ is open in $X$. But how to show $\phi(G)$ is open in $G(f)$? Please give a hint.

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of $\phi: X \to G(f)$ is the function which sends a point $(x, f(x))$ to $x$, aka the first projection map (restricted to just the graph $G(f)$). The map $\phi$ is open iff this restricted projection map is continuous. This restricted projection is the composite

$$G(f) \stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow} X \times Y \stackrel{\pi_1}{\to} X$$

of two continuous functions (the inclusion map $i$ is continuous because we are using the subspace topology on $G(f)$, as a subset of $X \times Y$), and is therefore continuous.

This is a long-winded way of reprising azarel's hint, but in some sense it explains what the situation is about. Drawing a picture of $\phi$ and its inverse may help (just use $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ to get the intuition).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that $\phi(G)=G(f)\cap(G\times Y) $